# SQL request with date

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a table with data and columns containing a date but separated into several columns :

- a column with the year,
- a column with the month,
- a column with the day.

I would like to keep only the data with a date that is less than 2 months.

I have tried to concat the date but the month and the day does not always have 2 characters. Sometimes it is one number : 1 for january for example.

Could you give some tips to make this request?

Thanks in advance,

```
select *
from etude
where concat(year,month,day) > NOW()
```

It is not working as expected

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time and to string handling, many products have their own functions.

Comment: `NOW()` looks like MySQL to me?  Is it?

Comment: it is the following : DB2400

Answer (score 1):

The `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()` function should be robust to months/days being either one or two digits:

```
SELECT *
FROM etude
WHERE TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(year, month, day), 'YYYYMMDD') > NOW();
```

But note that while this may fix your immediate problem, a much better long term solution would be to stop storing the various components of your date in separate columns.  Instead, just maintain a single bona-fide date/timestamp column.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,

Comment: Do you know how i can limit to the last 2 months? I would like to remove some values from this date but i didn't think of the change of year....

Comment: Please first let me know if this answer resolved your original question.

Comment: Side note: This will ignore the use of indices on any of those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use lpad function along with timestamp_format function

`select *
from etude
where timestamp_format(year || lpad(month,2,'0') || lpad(day,2,'0'), 'YYYYMMDD') > now();`

Answer (score 0):

If `keep only the data with a date that is less than 2 months` means `keep only the data with a date that is not earlier than 2 months from the current date`, then try this as is:

```
SELECT dt
FROM 
(
  SELECT date(digits(dec(year, 4)) || '-' || digits(dec(month, 2))|| '-' || digits(dec(day, 2))) dt
  FROM table
  (
  values 
    (2019, 1, 1)
  , (2019, 7, 13)
  ) etude (year, month, day)
)
WHERE dt > current date - 2 month;
```

Comment: the || signs are not possible, i don't know why....    I managed to find another solution that is working select date(concat(concat(concat(digits(dec(b.dtdba, 4)),'-'),concat(digits(dec(b.dtdbm, 2)),'-')),digits(dec(b.dtdbj, 2)))) dt
   from edec b but what this part used for values 
    (2019, 1, 1)
  , (2019, 7, 13)
  ) etude (year, month, day)

Comment: My statement works well on my IBM i V7.3. What's your db2 version? What's the full error message you get using these `||` signs?

Comment: I got the following error : Elément syntaxique | n'est pas correct. Eléments possibles : ) ,.

Comment: Now, i'm trying those 2 reuqests but i still got an error on dt value  select date(concat(concat(concat(digits(dec(b.dtdba, 4)),'-'),concat(digits(dec(b.dtdbm, 2)),'-')),digits(dec(b.dtdbj, 2)))) dt
from edec b
where dt >(current date - 2 months)

Comment: the second request i tried : SELECT dt
FROM
(
      select date(concat(concat(concat(digits(dec(b.dtdba, 4)),'-'),concat(digits(dec(b.dtdbm, 2)),'-')),digits(dec(b.dtdbj, 2)))) dt
   from edec b
)
WHERE dt > current date - 2 month;

Comment: Change SQL based on default date format on your system. Example given by @MarkBarinstein is based on date format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Satya `date('YYYY-MM-DD')` must work disregarding the default date format in the system.

Comment: @ClarisseB Contact your system administrator on why `||` symbols don't work in your system.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, thanks for the update. I was not aware that date function will accept both ISO date format and default date format when default date format is different from ISO date format

Answer (score 0):

to combine your 2 questions into 1 answer and using Satya's answer

select *
from etude
where timestamp_format(year || lpad(month,2,'0') || lpad(day,2,'0'), 'YYYYMMDD') > now() - 2 months;

Answer (score 0):

This is another option

```
select *
from etude
where DATE('0001-12-31') + (year -2) YEARS + month MONTHS + day DAYS > CURRENT DATE
```